# meaning of 傳 in 傳不習乎?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, classical-chinese

In Analects, chapter 4,
「吾日三省吾身
為人謀而不忠乎？
與朋友交而不信乎？
傳不習乎？」

I would translate it: Master Ceng said: everyday I check three things in myself:
do I plan my behavior without loyalty? do I make friends without confidence/trust (or deserving confidence - sincerity)? **do I propagate (disseminate) the Practice**.

James Legge (who is extremely competent in it) translates the last lines differently: **whether I may have not mastered and practiced the instructions of my teacher.**

Am I wrong that 傳 is about dissemination?

Comment: OT: We taught 論語 back then when I was in school (9th grade). This line is my favorite and I still remember it decades later!! :)

Answer (score 8):

[朱熹四書章句集注](http://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=89607) 「傳，謂受之於師。習，謂熟之於己。」

So `傳` means what you've received from your Master. James Legge's translation seems right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there're two comprehendings. The point is `曾子`'s identity, as a student of `孔子`, or as a teacher (when he became elder) ?

Basically I prefer to James Legge's translation, here `曾子` is supposed to be a student, and `传` means (the things) `teached`/`passed on` from the teacher.

If you think when `曾子` said these words he has become a teacher by himself, your understanding is reasonable too, even thouth I think it's more accurate to translate `传` as `teach`/`pass on`, so the whole sentence should be `Do I think twice and practice to check my thought/knowledge before I pass on them to others`?

Reference:
[“传不习乎”啥意思?](http://zuoye.baidu.com/question/4b32b7acd221aa80c5a7d57957e1f244.html)
[第二则 曾子曰：“吾日三省(xǐng)吾身：为人谋而不忠乎？与朋友交而不信乎？传不习乎？”（《学而》）](http://blog.hfyhjy.com/xucf/2014/07/30/%E7%AC%AC%E4%BA%8C%E5%88%99-%E6%9B%BE%E5%AD%90%E6%9B%B0%EF%BC%9A%E5%90%BE%E6%97%A5%E4%B8%89%E7%9C%81xing%E5%90%BE%E8%BA%AB%EF%BC%9A%E4%B8%BA%E4%BA%BA%E8%B0%8B%E8%80%8C%E4%B8%8D%E5%BF%A0/)

BTW: Some additional remarks about the translation of the first two sentence:

`为人谋` means `plan`/`do` sth for others.
`忠` means `elaborate`/`try one's best` here.
`信` means `to be credible`.